# making a class of Circle with constructors, accessors and mutators

Tags: java, constructor, accessor, mutators

im trying to create a class CircleClass but i have some errors that i cant get my head around. can i get help finding the errors?

```
import java.util.*;
public final class CircleClass
{
    //class fields
    private int diameter;
    private double area;

    /*Default Constructor
     *IMPORT none
     *EXPORT address of new CircleClass object
     *ASSERTION area 0 diameter 0 is default
     */
    public CircleClass()
    {
        area = 0.0;
        diameter = 0;
    }

    /*copy constructor
     *IMPORT inCircle (CircleClass)
     *EXPORT address of new CircleClass object
     *ASSERTION creates an object with an identical object state as the import
     */
    public CircleClass(CircleClass inCircleClass)
    {
        area = inCircleClass.getArea ();
        diameter = inCircleClass.getDiameter ();
    }

    /*alternate constructor
     *IMPORT inDiameter (integer)
     *EXPORT address of new Circle object
     *ASSERTION creates an object if imports are valid or fails otherwise
     */
    public CircleClass (int inDiameter)
    {
        if (validateNumber (inDiameter))
        {
            diameter = inDiameter;
            area = calcArea (diameter);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid value");
        }
    }
    /*SUB setArea
     *IMPORT area (real)
     *EXPORT none
     *ASSERTION sets the area if import is valid
     */
    public void setArea (double area)
    {
        if (area >= 0.0)
        {
            area = inArea;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid area value");
        }
    }

    /*SUB setDiameter
     *IMPORT inDiameter (integer)
     *EXPORT none
     *ASSERTION sets diater if valid
     */
    public void setDiameter (int inDiameter)
    {
        if ( validateNumber(inDiameter))
        {
            diameter = inDiameter;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid diameter");
        }
    }

    //ACCESSORS
    public int getDiameter ()
    {
        return diameter;
    }

    public double getArea ()
    {
        return area;
    }
    //SUB equals
    //IMPORT diameter
    //EXPORT same (boolean)
    //ASSERTION same = true if diameter is same as inDiameter
    public boolean equals (int diameter)
    {
        boolean same = false;
        if (diameter == inDiameter)
        {
            same = true;
        }
        return same;
    }

    //SUB equals
    //IMPORT inObject
    //EXPORT same (booleana)
    public boolean equals (Object inObject)
    {
        boolean same = false;
        if (inObject instanceof CircleClass)
        {
            CircleClass inCircle = (CircleClass) inObject;
            same = (diameter == inCircle.getDiameter);
        }
    }

    //SUB clone
    //IMPORT none
    //EXPORT cloneCircleClass (Object)
    //ASSERTION returns cloned object of current object
    public Object clone ()
    {
        CircleClass cloneCircleClass;
        cloneCircleClass = new CircleClass ( diameter, area);
        return cloneCircleClass;
   }
    //PRIVATE SUB validateNumber
    //IMPORT inDiameter
    //EXPORT valid
    //ASSERTION number should be gtreater or equal to 0
    private boolean validateNumber (int inDiameter)
    {
        return (inDiameter >= 0);
    }

    //SUB calcArea
    //IMPORT inDiameter
    //EXPORT area
    //ASSERTION calculates area
    private boolean calcArea (int diameter)
    {
        double radius, area;
        radius = (double)diameter / 2.0;
        area = Math.PI * radius * radius;
        return area;
    }
}
```

the errors i get is boolean cant be converted to double

finding symbols error

and no suitable constructor found for circleClass

im new making class objects so i have no idead what the last error means. thanks for the help

Comment: 1. `boolean calcArea`, you return `area`, a `double`, but the method expects a `boolean` return. 2. your parameter is called `area` and not `inArea`. same for `diameter` and `inDiameter`. Also `getDiameter` is a method, but you are calling it like a accessible variable. you forgot the parathesis there `getDiameter()`. 3. There is no `CircleClass(int, double)` constructor, so your `clone` method can´t create and return a new instance there. Either create one, or use one of the existing ones. `equals (Object inObject)` doesn´t have a `return` while it expects a `return`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your function `boolean calcArea(int diameter)` is returning boolean. Should be just `double`
2. You have not created a constructor like this `public CircleClass (int diameter, gouble area) {}`
3. In java it is better to write the `{` after `()` (not from new line)

   ```
   public void setArea(double area) {
       if (area >= 0.0) {
           this.area = area;
       } else {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid area value");
       }
   }
   ```

   this setter function is correct. Look at yours and correct others.

There are more mistakes, but try to fix these.